# On pressing chrome extension shortcut, operation keeps on performing if the shortcut key is pressed

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

When I press a shortcut assigned to a chrome extension, as long as shortcut keys is pressed, the operations keeps on performing. I have tried it with multiple extension. Is it intentional behaviour? Do extension developer need to handle it on their end? Or not?

Answer (score 0):

Is it intentional behaviour as when you open a text editor, you keep on pressing any key and see its echo on monitor :-)

This is unless the developer has planned a different behavior